Yii2 - How does database query caching work?
Given
    public function getScheduleSelect() {
        $duration = 86400;     // cache query results for 1 day (60*60*24 secs).
        $dependency = new DbDependency();
        $dependency->sql = 'SELECT MAX(`modifieddatetime`) FROM {{%schedule}}';

        return ArrayHelper::map(
                        $this->find()
                                ->select('schedule')
                                ->orderBy('schedule')
                                ->distinct()
                                ->asArray()
                                ->cache($duration, $dependency)
                                ->all(),
                        'schedule', 'schedule');
    }

If I were to change $duration to 0 (zero), or NULL, would the cache stay forever unless the $dependency changed? Or would never check again?
Basically, what I went is to have the query run only when the $dependency changes,

The documentation says 0 duration means "infinity". If you pass null as duration it will use the value set in $defaultDuration property instead.
In fact what "infinity" means depends on what caching engine you are using.
For example yii\caching\FileCache sets expiration to 1 year when you pass 0 as duration.
Memcache doesn't set specific expiration but your data might be removed when cache is full and needs space for new entries.
yii\caching\ArrayCache only keeps cached data in memory so it will be available only during current request and whole cache will be gone for next request.

"Basically, what I went is to have the query run only when the $dependency changes," So if I put 0 in duration, it will be there for 1 year, or until the dependency changes?

Yes if you put in 0 duration, it will stay in cache as long as possible or until it's invalidated by dependency.

But honestly, in your specific case I'm not sure the cache will be significant improvement. The query you are trying to cache should be fast enough if you have index over schedule column. And because you are using DbDependency there will always be at least one SQL query executed each time.

I have no control over the tables, so can't add index. The table I'm running the query on has over 100k records and gains about 60-100 records a day. The DbDependancy runs on a different table, but the info in the schedule column comes from there.  The schedule table only has 10-20 records and doesn't change often.
